# Updating NodeJS version on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: node.js, npm, apt, ubuntu-22.04

I'm trying to upgrade my NodeJS 12.22.09 to version 16 or newer, but when I enter the command `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` it returns this error below:

```
Preparing to unpack …/12-nodejs_16.16.0-deb-1nodesource1_amd64.deb …
Unpacking nodejs (16.16.0-deb-1nodesource1) over (12.22.9~dfsg-1ubuntu3) …
dpkg: error processing archive /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-hIlTWe/12-nodejs_16.16.0-deb-1nodesource1_amd64.deb (—unpack):
 trying to overwrite ‘/usr/include/node/common.gypi’, which is also in package libnode-dev 12.22.9~dfsg-1ubuntu3
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Preparing to unpack …/13-snapd_2.56.2+22.04ubuntu1_amd64.deb …
Unpacking snapd (2.56.2+22.04ubuntu1) over (2.55.5+22.04) …
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-hIlTWe/12-nodejs_16.16.0-deb-1nodesource1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 20):

There is a npm package called "[n](https://www.npmjs.com/package/n)" that handles node version management. Additionally, it supports convenient version naming, such as "current, "lts" or "18.12.1".

So, in your shell, type these commands:

```bash
sudo npm install -g n
sudo n lts
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like *nodejs* and *libnode* are having a conflict because they are trying to install the same file **'/usr/include/node/common.gypi'** which is causing an error.
To solve this, you can first remove the *libnode* package by using `sudo apt remove libnode-dev`.
Once it is removed, you can retry the *nodejs* upgrade command `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`.

Answer (score 1):

`sudo npm install -g --force node@latest`

Use that command, and it will fix your problem. The only issue with that is it will rewrite your node folder.